# Get client IP while using mode_proxy_wstunnel

Tags: php, apache, websocket, mod-proxy

I'm using the `mod_proxy_wstunnel` on `Apache 2.4.18`. So, all the requests are forwarded from

```
wss://url.com ==> ws://10.22.22.12:12345
```

in the WebSocket server code, I used

```
socket_getpeername($client, $clientIP);
echo $clientIP;
```

to get the Client IP address But, IP is always unexpected it shows server's IP i.e: `10.22.22.12`
It works normally with no proxy. So, is there a way to get client's IP instead of Server's while using `mod_proxy_wstunnel`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at the header of websocket connection, I found the following string.

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 145.24.35.40:12345
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Origin: https://www.domain.com
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.111 Safari/537.36
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,id;q=0.6
Cookie: __zlcmid=Y7fAKwRoP7ssZA; _ga=GA1.2.259560791.1452107273
Sec-WebSocket-Key: w8Mp2n2lp6R5vnYaeEWsPw==
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits
X-Forwarded-For: 22.22.22.22       <<=== Your IP
X-Forwarded-Host: ws.domain.com
X-Forwarded-Server: ws.domain.com
Upgrade: WebSocket
Connection: Upgrade
```

`X-Forwarded-For` contains what I was looking for. but I'm not sure if its the correct way to achieve the goal. I'll go for it until there is a better solution.